# Handling bad items in map function in Spark

Tags: exception, apache-spark, pyspark

What is an elegant way to deal with exceptions in map functions in Spark?

For example with:

```
exampleRDD= ["1","4","7","2","err",3]
exampleRDD=exampleRDD.map(lambda x: int(x))
```

This will not work because it will fail on the "err" item.

How can I filter out faulty rows and execute map on the rest, without anticipating the kind of error that I will encounter in every row?

One could do something like defining a function:

```
def stringtoint(x):
    try:
        a=int(x)
    except:
        a=-99
    return a
```

And then filter/map. But this doesn't seem as graceful as could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can directly apply filter then map

sample scala code

```
exampleRDD.filter(r=>NumberUtils.isNumber(r)).map(r=> int(r))
```

or use flatmap

```
exampleRDD.flatMap(r=> {if (NumberUtils.isNumber(r)) Some(int(r)) else  None})
```